# Run command on multiple machines and print the corresponding ip address also

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am running one same grep command on multiple machines from bastion machine. In addition to grep results, I want to print the corresponding IP address too.

```
ssh core@1.5.4.7 sudo grep -A 2 hi /home/abc.txt
ssh core@1.5.3.9 sudo grep -A 2 hi /home/abc.txt
```

I tried:

```
ssh core@1.5.4.7 "sudo grep -A 2 hi /home/abc.txt && hostname" 
ssh core@1.5.3.9 "sudo grep -A 2 hi /home/abc.txt && hostname"
```

But it only printed hostname of `1.5.3.9` machine at the end and that too only once.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Just echo the IP address before you run the ssh command.

Comment: (1) Do you want the host ***name***, or do you want the (numeric) IP address?  If you want the IP address, why are you using `hostname`?  Have you looked at the man page for `hostname` to see what options it has?  (2) `&&` means run the second command only if the first one succeeded.  `grep` “fails” unless it finds something, so if ```/home/abc.txt``` didn’t contain “hi” on 1.5.3.9, the `hostname` command isn’t going to run.  Use `;` to run the second command unconditionallt.

Comment: I fully endorce @DopeGhoti's response below... that being said I have a meta question... I see you are using the user "core".  Is this on CoreOS? (I'm a part of the CoreOS team).  If so, a better way to do this may be to grab information out of the meta-data service from your provider or to grab it from ` cat /etc/environment`, depending on what the final goal is.

Answer (score 2):

Well you already have the IP address; so you can just use it:

```
for host in 1.5.4.7 1.5.3.9; do
    ssh core@$host "sudo grep -A 2 hi /home/abc.txt" && \
    printf "%s\n" "$host"
done
```

Running `hostname` like you are in the example code in your question will output the *hostname*, not the *IP Address* which you said you wanted.

Using `&&` to separate commands will only run the subsequent command if (and only if) the exit code of the presequent command is zero; if `grep` finds no matches, it will not return a zero and the second command will not be executed.

Further, while not knowing much about your specific use-case, I generally find it easy when running things like this to show the host *before* the output of what is to be run on the host rather than *after*, but this is as simple as moving the `printf` statement (or, if you prefer, you can use `echo "$host"` in its lieu).

Comment: This works but it also simply prints the IP of the machine where it could not find that pattern.

Comment: Updated to only print hostname if matches to the `grep` are found.